# Microsoft Teams - Cannot add User to Contacts [Error: We couldn't add a buddy to the group]

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

We have three Office 365 Business Users, all of whom have the role **Global administrator**. In addition, each user has a license for **Microsoft Teams Commercial Cloud**.

[image]

In Microsoft Teams > Teams > Manage Team, everyone has the Role **Owner**.

In Teams > Chat > Contacts > Favorites > Add a contact to this group, I can select the name of a co-owner, but clicking Add results in the message:

[image]

Note that the organization is not using Active Directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently had a ticket open with Microsoft for this exact issue and we came across a fix. It seems like the issue is to do with the mail attribute not being filled for users, this happens if you do not have an Exchange license assigned.

We're still using an on-prem mail solution, so we aren't using O365 for Exchange. However, assigning a O365 E3/E5 trial license to the user (which should include an Exchange license) fills in the mail attribute for the user. You can use the graph explorer to query a user's attributes:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Use a GET request, beta, and query the user with the following: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/**emailaddresshere**

We've also found that removing the trial license after a few hours keeps the mail attribute filled, which in turn should resolve this.

Comment: Applying the O365 E5 trial license worked, but it took around 12 hours before we were able to add users to groups as normal.

Comment: This seems to have worked though we used E3 licenses and it took almost 24 hours and signing in/out of teams to get the email address to tag on the person's profile.

Answer (score 0):

My fix doesn't relate much to AD or Office 365 attributes.

That feature requires prior communication with the user for it to work.

If you go to `Calls -> Speed Dial -> New group` and try to create a group with user you never talked to it's going to give you error.

What you can do is simply go to `Calls -> Contacts -> Find User -> Add as Contact`.

Once that is done Speed Dial group will work. Most likely any chats with the user would have the same effect.